# e.preventDefault() prevents the default behavior, but return false not. Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, submit, preventdefault

I have the following simple form:

```
<form action="" id="myForm">
    Use <code>return false</code> (if not checked,
    <code>e.preventDefault()</code> will be used):
    <input type="checkbox" id="myCheckbox" checked>

    <br/>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit me">
</form>
```

Then, the JavaScript side:

```
document.getElementById("myForm").addEventListener("submit", function (e) {
    if (document.getElementById("myCheckbox").checked) {
        return false;    
    }
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Why `return false` does **NOT** prevent the default behavior, while `e.preventDefault()` works as supposed?

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14961657/1420197):

> `return false` is doing 3 separate things when you call it:
>
> 1. `event.preventDefault();`
> 2. `event.stopPropagation();`
> 3. Stops callback execution and returns immediately when called.

So, `event.prevendDefault()` is called. Does this happen in a jQuery callback only?

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/dtL8P/)

Comment: In jQuery only, yes, but not in vanilla JS.

Comment: @Teemu That's my guess, as well. I always believed that `return false` is handled by browser, not by jQuery.

Comment: You could have read the accepted answer of the question that you have specified as well.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are attaching your event through `addEventListener`, not via the `onsubmit` attribute of the HTML `form` element itself, you need to set your return value through the event which is passed to the event handler using `returnValue`. This is why you see `preventDefault` working - because it is a property of the event. Try this:

```
document.getElementById("myForm").addEventListener("submit", function (e) {
    if (document.getElementById("myCheckbox").checked) {
        e.returnValue = false; // <- Note
    }
    else {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/dtL8P/3/)

The difference is that because `return` is not called, execution will continue passed that statement, so you need to amend your logic accordingly. As such, I added the `else` block.

Comment: You mean *`onsubmit` attribute* instead of `onclick`, right?

Comment: @IonicãBizãu yes, thank you! Too early in the morning :)

Comment: In Romania is morning too. :-) You could simply do: `return e.returnValue = false;` that looks much better. ;-) Can you please add some docs references? Why returning `false` to `addEventListener` doesn't prevent the default behavior while `onsubmit='return false'` do?

Comment: I honestly did not know that there was a difference between using `on*` event handlers and `addEventListener`.

Comment: What's this `returnValue` stuff? Afaik `returnValue` belongs to the legacy IE event handling model, and is totally a custom property in modern browsers? Have I missed something lately?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Any feedback on these comments?